# How to Save and Display a Video Simultaneously using C# Aforge.NET framework?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, aforge, video-recording

I am able to display the video from my webcam or any other integrated device into a picturebox . Also i am able to Save the video into an avi file using FFMPEG DLL files.
I want to do both things simultaneously ie Save the video in the avi file as well as at the same time display the live feed too.
This is for a surveillance project where i want to monitor the live feed and save those too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace cam_aforge1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool DeviceExist = false;
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void getCamList()
    {
        try
        {
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
                throw new ApplicationException();

            DeviceExist = true;
            foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(device.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; //make dafault to first cam
        }
        catch (ApplicationException)
        {
            DeviceExist = false;
            comboBox1.Items.Add("No capture device on your system");
        }
    }

    private void rfsh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getCamList();
    }

    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (start.Text == "&Start")
        {
            if (DeviceExist)
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrameSave);
                CloseVideoSource();
                videoSource.DesiredFrameSize = new Size(160, 120);
                //videoSource.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
                videoSource.Start();
                label2.Text = "Device running...";
                start.Text = "&Stop";
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "Error: No Device selected.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                CloseVideoSource();
                label2.Text = "Device stopped.";
                start.Text = "&Start";                    
            }
        }
    }
    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }

    Bitmap imgsave;
    private void video_NewFrameSave(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        imgsave = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    }

    private void CloseVideoSource()
    {
        if (!(videoSource == null))
            if (videoSource.IsRunning)
            {
                videoSource.SignalToStop();
                videoSource = null;
            }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "Device running... " + videoSource.FramesReceived.ToString() + " FPS";
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        CloseVideoSource();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    VideoFileWriter writer;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        writer = new VideoFileWriter();
        writer.Open("test.avi", width, height, 75, VideoCodec.MPEG4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteVideoFrame(imgsave);
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        writer.Close();
    }

}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not calling `button1_Click` from within `start_click`?